# Anonymous functions in JavaScript: two ways, same result

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to understand if there's a reason why I'd create two anonymous functions within an if/else block versus creating an anonymous function and putting the entire if/else block inside that function.

The tutorial (Code School) I'm going through suggested alerting one of two options like this:

```
var greeting;
var newCustomer = false;

if (newCustomer) {
  greeting = function () {
    alert("Hello, new customer.")
  };
} else {
  greeting = function () {
    alert("Hello, returning customer.")
  };
}

welcome(greeting);

function welcome(message) {
  message();
}
```

When I tried to write without referring to the tutorial, I ended up writing this, which produces the same result as above:

```
var greeting;
var newCustomer = false;

var greeting = function () {
  if (newCustomer) {
    alert("Hello, new customer.")
  } else {
    alert("Hello, returning customer.")
  }
}

welcome(greeting);

function welcome(message) {
  message();
}
```

Comment: you're not using anonymous function anywhere....

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: were you expecting some different behaviour, because that was obvious

Answer (score 0):

As with almost anything, it depends on the situation, and the best approach will depend on what you need to do. It's hard to say which is better in this artificial example, but the first approach has some merit because if `newCustomer` is already known when you're creating `greeting`, then it's better to carry out that decision logic up front, rather than putting it off for later. However, if it were me, I'd probably go with neither of those options and do this, which follows the DRY principle and is the best of both worlds (decision logic up front and the function created is always consistent):

```
var greetingText,
    greeting;
var newCustomer = false;

if (newCustomer) {
  greetingText = "Hello, new customer.";
} else {
  greetingText = "Hello, returning customer.";
}

greeting = function () {
    alert(greetingText);
}

welcome(greeting);

function welcome(message) {
  message();
}
```

That can then be shortened to:

```
var greetingText,
    greeting;
var newCustomer = false;

greetingText = "Hello, " + (newCustomer ? "new" : "returning") + " customer.";    

greeting = function () {
    alert(greetingText);
}

welcome(greeting);

function welcome(message) {
  message();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the difference is the different moment at which the `if` statement is evaluated. In the first case it's evaluated *once* right away, in the second case *every time* the function is called.

So you would use the first way if the condition can't change, so there is no reason to evaluate it over and over again. For example when you test for browser support of a specific method.

And you'd put the `if` statement inside the function for exactly the opposite reasons.